# Android how to run permission on the first runtime in OREO

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I want user when opening the app for the first time permission should ask instead of the second time.This bug is on oreo version

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            // only for gingerbread and newer versions

            Dexter.withActivity(getActivity())
                    .withPermissions(
                            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                            Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE
                    )
                    .withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport report) {
                            // check if all permissions are granted
                            if (report.areAllPermissionsGranted()) {
                                // do you work now

                            }

                            // check for permanent denial of any permission
                            if (report.isAnyPermissionPermanentlyDenied()) {
                                // permission is denied permenantly, navigate user to app settings
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> permissions, PermissionToken token) {
                            token.continuePermissionRequest();
                        }
                    })
                    .onSameThread()
                    .check();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this code starting from 6.0 up to 9.0 and it works. inside `onCreate()` method. add this.

**NOTE** `PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE == 1`

This is just a Sample code for runtime permission. you can change it

```
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Login.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Login.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Login.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Login.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Login.this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Login.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple request permissions at runtime.
This work for me!

```
List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        }
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE);
        }

        if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]),
                    REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
        }
```

Add this code to manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```